# How to remove_action inside class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions

i have class like this

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'My_class' ) ) {
    class My_class {
        public function __construct() {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( $this, 'change_title' ), 10 );
        }

        public function change_title() {
            echo 'The title';
        }
    }
}

return new My_class();
```

I trying to remove_action `change_title` by using

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array( 'My_class', 'change_title' ), 10 );
// or
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );
```

But it does not work because I don't really understand PHP OOP.
How can I do that, is it possible?

And can i remove it via a plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to remove it with `remove_action()` the way you've written it.

When you hooked it here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( $this, 'change_title' ), 10 );
```

The `$this` means that the function that's hooked is on this specific instance of `My_class`. When using `remove_action()` you need to pass the same instance of the class:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array( $instance, 'change_title' ), 10 );
```

(where `$instance` is the instance of the class).

The problem is that the instance of the class is not available anywhere else because you've instantiated into nothing:

```
return new My_class();
```

To remove the action you need to put the class instance into a variable and then use that variable to remove it later:

```
$my_class = new My_class();
```

Then in your other code:

```
global $my_class;

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array( $my_class, 'change_title' ), 10 );
```

Another option is that if `change_title` is [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) then you don't need a specific instance of the class to add and remove it from hooks.

So make the function static:

```
public static function change_title() {
    echo 'The title';
}
```

Then to hook a static method you do this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', array( 'My_class', 'change_title' ), 10 );
```

Which means you can remove it like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', array( 'My_class', 'change_title' ), 10 );
```

But whether your class/functions can or should be static is a larger architectural question that would depend on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, it's works on my theme. Another question: can i remove it via a plugin? The same way can work? Sorry, I haven't worked with the plugin ever

Comment: @ttn_ Yes. It doesn't matter if it was added by theme or plugin. You just need to care that you remove it after it has been added (and not before, so look out for order of execution)